# How to implement common part for user control with inheritage?

Tags: c#, silverlight, silverlight-4.0

I have some common parts for all user control. It's defined in an interface, say MyInterface.

Then I implement part of it in a class, say MyBaseClass:

```
class MyBaseClass : MyInterface    
{    
//......    
}
```

Then when I create a user control, I want to this user control has the implementation of the common part. So I want to change code behind for MyControl as:

```
public partial class MyControl : UserControl, MyBaseClass
    {
        public MyControl()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
```

but system will give me error. reason: Mybase is not partial class. if change MyBaseClass as partial, still get erro say something like "not allow mutiple base class".

One solution is like

```
public partial class MyUserControl : UserControl, MyInterface
    {
        public MyUserControl ()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
```

but this will cause duplicate implementation for each user control. Many copy & paste. I don't want to this way.

Tried following way:

```
public class MyBaseClass : UserControl, MyInterface
```

or

```
public partial class MyBaseClass : UserControl, MyInterface
```

I got error: 
Partial declarations of 'MyUserControl' must not specify different base classes

How to resove this problem?

Comment: C# doesn't support multiple inheritance... All you can try is to put the common code in some BaseUesrControl, which inherits from UserControl, and than inherit from this base.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you go with this:-

```
public class MyBaseClass : UserControl, MyInterface
```

Which you've tried but there is a twist.  When you then wnat to create a derived "UserControl" from this, start with a standard Usercontrol but then change the code-behind file to this:-

```
public partial class MyDerivedClass : MyBaseClass
```

**and**

change the Xaml to:-

```
<local:MyBaseClass x:Class="MyNamespace.MyDerivedClass"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyNamespace"
>
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
    </Grid>
</local:MyBaseClass>
```

Comment: Thank you. For my case, MyBaseClass is in another project(aseembly), I changed xaml as <MyCommon:MyBaseClass .....>....</MyCommon:MyBaseClass>, VS give me error as: 'MyCommon' is an undeclared prefix. Same as use local if put MyBaseClass in same project.

Comment: Thank you. figured out. SHould put local or MyCommon in xmlnl.